# Elastic : make a light count query (vs search query)

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I am accessing bulk data in elastic through R. For analytics purpose I need to query for data for a relatively long duration (say a month). The data for a month is approx 4.5 million rows and R goes out of memory.

Sample data is below (for 1 day):

```
dt <- as.Date("2015-09-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
frmdt <- strftime(dt,"%Y-%m-%d")
  todt <- as.Date(dt+1)
  todt <- strftime(todt,"%Y-%m-%d")

  connect(es_base="http://xx.yy.zzz.kk")
  start_date <- as.integer(as.POSIXct(frmdt))*1000
  end_date <- as.integer(as.POSIXct(todt))*1000


  query <- sprintf('{"query":{"range":{"time":{"gte":"%s","lte":"%s"}}}}',start_date,end_date)
  s_list <- elastic::Search(index = "organised_2015_09",type = "PROPERTY_SEARCH", body=query ,
                     fields = c("trackId", "time"), size=1000000)$hits$hits
  length(s_list)
[1] 144612
```

This result for 1 day has 144k records and is 222 MB. Sample list item below:

```
> s_list[[1]]
$`_index`
[1] "organised_2015_09"

$`_type`
[1] "PROPERTY_SEARCH"

$`_id`
[1] "1441122918941"

$`_version`
[1] 1

$`_score`
[1] 1

$fields
$fields$time
$fields$time[[1]]
[1] 1441122918941


$fields$trackId
$fields$trackId[[1]]
[1] "fd4b4ce88101e58623ba9e6e31971d1f"
```

Actually a summary count of number of items by "trackId" and "time" (summarize for every day) would suffice for analytics purpose. Hence I tried to transform this into a count query with aggregations. So I constructed the below query:

```
query < -'{"size" : 0,
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter": {
            "range": {
                "time": {
                    "gte": 1441045800000,
                    "lte": 1443551400000
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "articles_over_time": {
        "date_histogram": {
            "field": "time",
            "interval": "day",
            "time_zone": "+05:30"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "group_by_state": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "trackId",
                    "size": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}'

response <- elastic::Search(index="organised_recent",type="PROPERTY_SEARCH",body=query, search_type="count")
```

However I did not gain in speed or document size. i think I am missing something but not sure what.

Comment: Can you elaborate what happens when you run the aggregation query?

Comment: Did you figure this out? i'm the `elastic` author if you need any help. Opening an issue at the repo https://github.com/ropensci/elastic/issues may be faster as well